# Запись в файл логов

Tags: php, логирование

Хочу сделать запись логов файл. Что - то такого: Кнопку нажал - в текстовом документе появилась запись "Нажата кнопка". Но пошло что-то не так.

```
function logFile($textLog) {
$file = '(место для вашего пути) \logFile.txt';
$text = '\n';
$text .= print_r($textLog);//Выводим переданную переменную
$text .= '\n'. date('Y-m-d H:i:s') .'\n'; //Добавим актуальную дату после текста или дампа массива
$fOpen = fopen($file,'a');
fwrite($fOpen, $text);
fclose($fOpen);
}
```

Вызов происходит так

```
if( isset( $_POST['red'] ) )
    {
        echo "<body style= 'background-color:red;'>";
        $text = 'Красная кнопка';
        logFile($text);
    }
```

На экране появляется текст, а вот в файл не записываются действия. Как пофиксить можно?
Ps: код для кнопки

```
 <form method="POST">
        <input  type="submit" name="red" value ="red" >
    </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Откройте файл лога apache (по умолчанию в *nix-системах находится */var/log/apache2/errors.log.*) и посмотрите ошибки. Вполне возможно, что файла по адресу '(место для вашего пути) \logFile.txt' попросту не существует. Попробуйте для начала указать путь './logFile.txt' и пробовать создавать файл в текущей директории.
2. Если выполняете в ОС семейства *nix, смотрите на права исполняемого файла и директории в которой он находится. Так же владельца файла и директории, в которой он находится. Иначе будет ошибка 'access denied' при попытке создать/открыть файл. Посмотреть права и владельца можно выполнив команду 'ls -la'
3. Offtopic. Если хотите добавить перенос строки, то следует его указывать в двойных кавычках "\r\n". Все, что написано в одинарных кавычках '' выведется как текст

   ```
       function logFile($textLog) {
           $file = './logFile.txt';
           $text = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n"; //Добавим актуальную дату после текста или дампа массива
           $text .= $textLog;//Выводим переданную переменную
           $text .= "\n";
           $fOpen = fopen($file, 'a+');
           if ( $fOpen ){          
               fwrite($fOpen, $text);
               fclose($fOpen);
           } else {
               echo 'Wrong open log-file.';
           }
       }

       if (isset( $_POST['red'] ) ) {
           echo "<body style= 'background-color:red;'>";
           $text = 'Красная кнопка';
           logFile($text);
       }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Лучше использовать `file_put_contents()` ([см. здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php)) вместо связки `fopen()`, `fwrite()` и `fclose()`.
2. Проверь права на запись в файл если файл существует или права на запись в папку если файл не существует на момент открытия. Для проверки можно использовать `is_writable()` ([см. здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-writable.php))
3. Вместо `\n` лучше использовать встроенную константу `PHP_EOL`

Comment: Что-то это не очень помогло. А добавило ошибок.

Comment: И да. Файл доступен для записи. Проверила по второму пункту :)

Comment: @Owl_Livi в логах что-то есть?

Comment: К сожалению, нет.

Comment: @Owl_Livi по поводу `fopen()` исправил свой ответ

Comment: В справке было написано про то, что отредактировали. Ниже ответ помог. Спасибо за Вашу помощь :)